# Solve the equation $\sqrt{\cos x}=2\cos x-1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Solve this. Show work as detailed as possible.

$$\sqrt{\cos x} = 2\cos x-1$$

My work:

\begin{align*}
2\cos x  & = \sqrt{\cos x}+1\\
\cos x  & = \frac{\sqrt{\cos x}+1}{2}\\
x  & = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\cos x}+1}{2}\right)
\end{align*}

Is that correct ?????

Comment: No, because you have not found $x$.

Comment: You still have $x$ on both sides of the equation, so you have not explicitly expressed the solutions.

Comment: so what should I do please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First square both sides, then we find
$$\cos x = (2\cos x -1)^2= 4\cos^2x -4\cos x+1.$$
Bringing everything to the same side gives
$$4\cos^2x -5\cos x+1 = 0.$$
This can be solved like a normal quadratic equation, which gives
$$\cos x = \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{(-5)^2-4\cdot4}}{2\cdot 4}.$$
This then gives
$$\cos x = \frac{5\pm \sqrt{9}}{8}= \frac{5\pm 3}{8}.$$

Thus we find
$$\cos x = 1, \qquad \text{or} \qquad \cos x = \frac{1}{4}.$$

Solving for $x$ gives
$$x = 0, \qquad \text{or} \qquad x = \arccos{\frac{1}{4}}.$$

However, if we now check our original results, we see that only $x =0$ is a correct solution. Note that this is a solution on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. One can extend this easily to all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The $\cos x=\frac{1}{4}$ does not work on the initial equation. If you square both sides, you must check afterwards because extraneous solutions are possible.

Comment: Well, in fact it does work if we take $\sqrt{1/4} = -1/2$, which is of course possible.

Comment: No, $\sqrt{a}$ for $a\ge 0$ is a function and must take only one value, and by convention it is the non-negative one. In your comment $\sqrt{1/4}=1/2$.

Comment: I will fix this.

Comment: Even then, you're wrong in saying that $\cos x=1$ or $\cos x=\frac{1}{4}$ implies $x=0$ or $x=\arccos\frac{1}{4}$. There are infinitely many solutions, generated by $x=2\pi n$ or by $x=\pm\arccos\frac{1}{4}+2\pi n$ for integers $n$, respectively.

Comment: Given the interval $[0,2\pi]$ this are the solutions.

Comment: It was not given that $x\in [0,2\pi]$ in the problem statement.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{\cos x}=2\cos x-1$$

$$\iff 2\left(\sqrt{\cos x}-1\right)\left(\sqrt{\cos x}+\frac{1}{2}\right)=0$$

$\sqrt{\cos x}\ge 0$, so $$\sqrt{\cos x}=1\iff \cos x=1\iff x=2\pi n$$

for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: You forgot one result.

Comment: @Martigan No, the $\cos x=\frac{1}{4}$ that others got is extraneous and appeared after squaring both sides.

Comment: You are right, I spoke too fast... my bad!

Comment: extraneous result?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Square both sides first, and then solve the quadratic equation to find what $\cos x$ is.

**Hint 2**

$$\cos x = (2\cos x -1)^2= 4\cos^2x -4\cos x+1$$
$$4t^2-5t+1=0\quad \longrightarrow \quad \cos x = t = ?$$
$$x=?$$

Comment: I really did that before I posted the question but I didn't get the correct result that's why I posted question here to get some help

Comment: @user155971 You should have posted your earlier work with this try, not the one you showed just now.

Comment: @user155971 - you get one more hint.

Comment: I got $$t=1$$ and $$t=1/4$$ and when substitution in cos then $$cosx=1$$ or $$cosx=1/4$$

Comment: @user155971 - Ok. Now what is $x$?

Comment: so, $$ x=cos^{-1}(1)=0$$ or $$ x= cos^{-1}(1/4)=75.522$$

Comment: No, $\cos x=\frac{1}{4}$ is extraneous and does not work on the initial equation. It appeared after squaring both sides of the equation.

Comment: @user155971: squaring both sides can introduce additional solutions don't forget to try them both in the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\cos x=t$ and solve the equation for $t$. Then, undo the change and make sure the solution make sense (e.g. if $t=2$, then theres is no valid $x$).

Comment: good idea , I will apply it now many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $\cos x = c$

\begin{align*}
c & = 4c^2 - 4c + 1\\
0 & = 4c^2 - 5c + 1\\
0 & = (4c-1)(c-1)
\end{align*}

$c = 1/4$ or $c = 1$

Check and see that only $c=1$ works so

$ x= 2n \pi  $

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: $c=\frac{1}{4}$ does not work. You've added extraneous solutions after squaring both sides.